# How to match request to response while proxying packets?

Tags: mysql, networking, go, tcp, proxy

I'm working on MySQL proxy with browser based GUI.
Core of an app looks like:

```
//Trying to connect to server
rightConn, err := net.Dial("tcp", l.rightAddr)
if err != nil {
    return
}
defer rightConn.Close()

wg.Add(2)
//Start passing packets from client to server
go func() {
    defer wg.Done()
    l.Pipe(leftConn, rightConn)
}()

//Start passing packets from server to client
go func() {
    defer wg.Done()
    l.Pipe(rightConn, leftConn)
}()
wg.Wait()
```

And here's definition of Pipe:

```
func (l *Lottip) Pipe(right, left net.Conn) {
for {
    pkt, err := mysql.ReadPacket(right)
    if err != nil {
        break
    }

    if _, err = mysql.WritePacket(pkt, left); err != nil {
        break
    }
}
```

}

The reason i'm using my custom proxy function instead of

```
go io.Copy(left, right)
go io.Copy(right, left)
```

is i have to parse each MySQL's Request/Response packet and prepare it for further processing.

As we all know MySQL client can send a lot of queries and get responses in random order.

**The problem is i cannot get how to match request to it's response**. While i'm piping using 2 goroutines(1 per direction) i can easily read server response but i don't know to what request it responding.

I've examined request/response between MySQL client and server via Wireshark and found no mention for packet_id or query_id or similar

Comment: I am not sure about Go code but I think this has to do with session ids on mysql and not with Go. I wrote this couple of months back experiencing prepared statements/ temporary tables not working with mysql proxy https://pregmatch.org/read/mysql-proxy-prepared%20statements-not-working. This is not solution just observation from my side.

Comment: Well, I can definitely map any request\response to it's session. But how to map response to it's request wihin that session? I'll take a look at your post, thanks a lot.

Comment: Any other ideas guys?